# Using findOne and findOneAndUpdate with HTTP request (mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am making an api rest in which I want to make HTTP requests using Postman, specifically I want to perform a search or update a mongodb document, but this must be by an id which is not the doc_id that provides mongo

models Schema

```
'use strict'

 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 const Schema   = mongoose.Schema

 const infoClientSchema = Schema ({
  idusr: String,                          /*this is require*/
  name: String,
  phone: Number,
  address: String,
  riff: String,
  state: String,
  city: String,
  email: {type: String}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('InfoCli',infoClientSchema)
```

Controller (This is the get method I know using findById and is working)

```
'use strict'

const InfoCli = require('../models/infoclient')

function getInfoCli(req, res){
    let infocliId = req.params.infocliId

    InfoCli.findById(infocliId, (err, infocli) =>{
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error making 
                                                    request: $(err)'})

        if (!infocli) return res.status(404).send({message: 'The client does 
                                                               not exist '})

        res.status(200).send({infoclient: infocli})     
    })
}
```

Controller (This is the get method which I thought would work using findOne)

```
function getInfoByUsr(req, res){
    let idusr = req.body.idusr

    InfoCli.findOne(idusr, (err, infocli) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error making 
                                                    request: $(err)'})

        if (!infocli) return res.status(404).send({message: 'The client does 
                                                               not exist '})

        res.status(200).send({infoclient: infocli})

        console.log(infocli) /*The console is not showing anything*/
    })
 }
```

Controller (This is the put method which I thought would work using findOneAndUpdate)

```
function updateByUsr(req, res){
    let idusr  = req.body.idusr
    let update = req.body

    InfoCli.findOneAndUpdate(idusr, update, (err, infocliUpdate) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error making 
                                                    request: $(err)'})

        if (!idusr) return res.status(404).send({message: 'The client does 
                                                               not exist '})

        res.status(200).send({infocliente: infocliUpdate})
    })
 }
```

Routes (not 100% sure about this)

```
const express     = require('express')
const InfoCliCtrl = require('../controllers/infoclient')
const api         = express.Router()

api.get('/infoclient/:infocliId', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoCli) /*working*/
api.get('/infoclient/:idusr', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoByUsr)
```

Comment: what is your question here?

Comment: simple, what is the right method between controllers and routes for findOne and findOneAndUpdate? I just need a simple solution for my method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you simply need to change the line `let idusr = req.body.idusr` in your *getInfoByUsr()* function to `let idusr = req.params.idusr`

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params

Also check the syntax of your *findOne* and *findOneAndUpdate* query (because `idusr` is not a Mongo _id but sort of custom String id):

```
InfoCli.findOne({ idusr: idusr }, (err, infocli) => { ...
InfoCli.findOneAndUpdate({ idusr: idusr }, update, (err, infocliUpdate) => {..
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne

Comment: It still does not work, but I'm trying to get the solution through those links, thank you very much

Comment: Yes indeed. Take a look at my edited answer. (And you need to change your route pattern too to not point in same place)

Answer (score 1):

In your app.js/server.js

you should have [bodyparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) installed

```
api.get('/infoclient/:infocliId', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoCli) 
api.post('/infoclient/:idusr', InfoCliCtrl.updateByUsr)
```

If you are passing data as URL parameter, like this `/infoclient/:infocliId` then you can access that using `req.params.infocliId`

If you are passing using POST body then you can access data using `req.body`.

> In infoClient.js

**To fetch user data**

```
exports.getInfoCli = function(req, res, next){
   var incomingData = req.params.infocliId;
   InfoCli.findOne({idusr: incomingData}, function(err, data){
    if(err){
       return res.status(500);
    } else {
       return res.status(200).send({infoclient: data})
    }
   });
}
```

Call the above code by

GET - `http://localhost:port/infoclient/3874234634` this `3874234634` is your infocliId you need to pass in route

**To update user data**

```
exports.updateByUsr = function(req, res, next){
   var userId = req.params.idusr;
   var updateData = req.body;

   InfoCli.findOneAndUpdate({idusr: userId}, updateData, {new: true }, function(err, data){  
    if(err){
       return res.status(500);
    } else {
       return res.status(200).send(data)
    }
   });
}
```

In the update code we have used `{new : true}` is to return updated document from DB

Call the above code by

POST method - `http://localhost:port/infoclient/3874234634` with data in POST body `{name: 'pikachu', phone: 12345, ...}`

so you read the userid in url parameter using `req.params` and body data in `req.body`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, your answers help me to correct many things in the code.
The problem was a horrible mistake in the routes

See how I was using the same path for two requests

```
api.get('/infoclient/:infocliId', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoCli) /*working*/
api.get('/infoclient/:idusr', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoByUsr)
```

The problem was that when I used the identifier for **idusr** it was in conflict with the **ObjectId** search

Now

```
api.get('/infoclient/idusr/:idusr', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoByUsr)
```